# NSInteger counts times 4?

Tags: ios, increment, nsinteger

I don't understand why this NSInteger counter increments to exactly 4 times the true value of database rows.  Maybe this is stupid but I really just don't get it...

Thanks so far :)

```
NSInteger *i;
i = 0;

for ( NSDictionary *teil in gText ) {

    //NSLog(@"%@", [teil valueForKey:@"Inhalt"]);

    [databaseWrapper addEntry:[teil valueForKey:@"Inhalt"] withTyp:[teil valueForKey:@"Typ"] withParagraph:[teil valueForKey:@"Paragraph"]];

    i+=1;
}

NSLog(@"Number of rows created: %d", i);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because i is a pointer and you are incrementing the pointer value which will most likely be in steps of 4 (size of NSInteger pointer).  Just remove the pointer * reference and you should be good.

```
NSInteger i = 0;

for ( NSDictionary *teil in gText ) {
```

In theory you COULD do this the hard way.

```
NSInteger *i;
*i = 0;
for ( NSDictionary *teil in gText ) {
...
*i = *i + 1;
...
```

From:
[Foundation Data Types Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html)

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
#endif
```

Comment: Ah, so NSInteger isn't a regular Object like all the other NSS..., it's a primitive type?

Comment: Yes, actually it's interesting because it's a typedef to either long or int.  I'll include the snip from the documentation.

Comment: Well,seems like making 64 bit more intuitive...fine for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`i` is not declared as an `NSInteger`, it's declared as a pointer to an `NSInteger`.

Since an `NSInteger` is 4 bytes, when you add 1, the pointer actually increases by the size of 1 `NSInteger`, or 4 bytes.

```
i = 0;
...
i += 1; //Actually adds 4, since sizeof(NSInteger) == 4
...
NSLog(@"%d", i); //Prints 4
```

This confusion is arising because `NSInteger` is not an object, so you don't need to declare a pointer to it. Change your declaration to this for the expected behaviour:

```
NSInteger i = 0;
```

Comment: "i is not declared as an NSInteger, it's declared as an NSInteger." uhhh... wat?